# ESS C-RET does not add a new line at the end of buffer

Tags: ess

According to the doc, since ESS 12.09

`ESS: ess-eval-*-and-step functions go to next empty line at eob, instead of staying at the last line.`

However, when I hit `C-RET` at the end, it still says on the last line.

`C-h c C-RET` confirms that `C-RET` is being bound to `ess-eval-region-or-line-and-step`.

My ESS version is 16.10

Comment: I'm interested in this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I found the behavior to be inconsistent -- sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, somehow conditional on the kind of code I sent to the inferior buffer. I temporarily have "(setq next-line-add-newlines t)` so that I can `C-n` to add new line when necessary. I went back to RStudio too :)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling CUA Mode worked for me as C-RET is bound to cua-rectangle-mark....

I dont like remapping basic stuff, but here is a potential workaround:
[rebind C-RET in cua-mode to a different key?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37404/rebind-c-ret-in-cua-mode-to-a-different-key)