# rebind C-RET in cua-mode to a different key?

Tags: key-bindings, cua-mode

I use column editing in cua-mode (`cua-selection-mode`) a lot. A main issue I have is that the most frequently used keybinding,  `C-RET` (Control + Return), doesn't work in most terminals (Ubuntu 16.04, Emacs 24.5), or with `emacs -nw`.

I did some research and found that this is a nasty problem as `C-RET` is often neglected by terminals and emacs does not receive it at all in non-GUI modes.

As a work-around, ***how can I rebind the functions of `C-RET` in cua mode to another key, e.g. `C-^`***, that is [not lost along the way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161725)?

(I searched around here and only found questions about how to 
[Unbind C-RET in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14500/17852))

Also, is it possible to rebind in a way that allow *both* the original key `C-RET` and the new key `C-^` to work?

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [Remapping Commands]()https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing the potential solutions I can find, this is what worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04, emacs 24.5):

```
(setq cua-rectangle-mark-key (kbd "C-^"))
(cua-selection-mode t)
```

Basically, define the key in question to the new value before enabling `cua-mode` in init file. This seems to work both for `emacs -nw`, and terminals local and remote (windows and Linux).